# Google Sheets Remove text in string after one of multiple characters hit

Tags: string, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column of strings like this:

This is a random string - with some extra text
Another string | with extra text
Third string (with extra text)

I want to do a formula that removes selected character and everything after it, characters i want to remove are "|", "(" and "-". So results above would be:

This is a random string
Another string
Third string

I found this formula in another stackoverflow thread:
=LEFT(C4,SEARCH("|",C4)-1)

It can only do one value though, i need three. Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: Use split and text join or substitute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some method:

regexplace==>

```
=substitute(REGEXREPLACE(C6,"[,;|']",""),"  "," ")
```

substitute in substitute ==>

```
=substitute(SUBSTITUTE(substitute(substitute(substitute(C6,"'",""),"|",""),":",""),";",""),",","")
```

Split and join or textjoin==>

```
=substitute(join(" ",split(C6,":,{}()'\|;""",true,true)),"  "," ")
```

Get the first before special character:

```
=array_constrain(split(C11,":,{}()'\|;""",true,true),1,1)
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this but what it does is only remove the selected characters. I want only the text UNTIL one of these characters show, then delete the rest

Comment: use the last, after split don't use join, but do query to get the col1

Comment: I add more formula, please look at the last formula

Comment: Your a hero, works flawlessly. Thanks so much :) Will try to understand the formula. Actually theres one small issue, it works for "|" and "(" but not for "-". I just added a "-" into the delimiter part and it works great now, cheers!